# SoapUI generated cxf web service client generation encoding utf-8 to iso-8859 issue

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cxf, soapui, iso-8859-1

I have a webs ervice client that consumes a web service which is generating a UTF-8 encoding.The client was worling until i decided to change the web service to return "registrationEmailError" in the String return value.Now the CXF client generated code is returning or converting this to "registratiâ€‹onEmailErrâ€‹or".How do i change this default ISO-8859 encoding to utf-8 in the SoapUI generated cxf client code ?

I see in the registrationResponse that the correct value "registrationEmailError" is being returned but somehow the CXF client code is I think defaulting it to iso-8859-1 and causing this issue ???

I changed the result returned to "ree" and it works fine.

I used SoapUI 3.1.6 to generate the cxf web service client code.
JDK 1.6.27

TIA,
Vijay

Comment: it seems that you used non-latin letter when typed "registrationEmailError" because there are utf-8 artifacts in two places. consider re-typing it correctly

Comment: Thanks,Artem for the reply.I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

wsdl2java support `-encoding` option.
In soapUI aon window Generate Code, Tab 'Custom Args' you can add in Tool Args: -encoding UTF8